# How to send file and object using postman?

Tags: java, spring, postman

I have an endpoint which is adding files and object. Here are the function parameters:

```java
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/request",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    consumes = {"multipart/form-data"}
)
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<Object> requestLicense(
    @RequestPart("properties") @Valid LicenseRequest request,
    @RequestPart("file1") @Valid @NotNull @NotBlank MultipartFile file1,
    @RequestPart("file2") @Valid @NotNull @NotBlank MultipartFile file2
) {
    ...
}
```

And I would like to send correct post method using postman but I do not know how to do it.
[image]

How do I do it or it is impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as mentioned by [Majid_Roustaei answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63499328/471663), a valid post to the method needs to contain 2 separate files parameters, namely `file1` and `file2` plus the `properties` parameter.

It is the purpose of the Multipart Form-Data.:

[image]

You are almost there !

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible and you have done lots of it yourself.

just remind that you have two files in your endpoint's requirements and they both are annotated with `@NotNull`, so you need to send two files with the specified names (which are `file1` and `file2` in your case).

these names should exactly be in the key part of your form-data.

have a look on this:

[image]